# Force close when clicking a Spinner inside a new Activity.

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-tabhost, forceclose

I've created a `TabHost` with three tabs in it. If I click one of my tabs,
an `Activity` with a `Spinner` will be opened. If I click that `Spinner`, my application force closes.

My Activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.employeepayslip);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  //Submit

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    idviewslip = extras.getString("idviewslip");

     empid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.empid1);
     empname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.empname1);
     empdesignation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.empdesignation);

    sp1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String>Adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,months);
    sp1.setAdapter(Adapter);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String>Adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,years);
    sp2.setAdapter(Adapter1);
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Check your logcat and see where it's crashing. If it's not clear from that, post your logcat and relevant code here.

Comment: Post your entire logcat. The exception probably propagated all the way up from somewhere else.

Comment: please give more specific log. But i guess your activity has not created completely yet.

Comment: thanks for all three who gave me Immediate Response .Now,I got the solution and Posted as an Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replaced the following

```
setContentView(R.layout.employeepayslip);
```

to

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.employeepayslip, null);
    this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```